# Difference between the use of "for" and "of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, of-for

I am always confused by the difference between the use of *for* and *of* in cases like these:

> 1. Principal component analysis *of* microarray data.
> 2. Principal component analysis *for* microarray data.

Which of these is correct? Is it OK to use both? If yes, when should I use 1. and 2., respectively?

Comment: It would help if you provided complete sentences as examples. It would also help if you simplified the jargon.

Comment: @John Satta. Sorry, I thought the jargon would not matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both examples are correct usage, but the meanings are different and very much dependent on the context.

If the microarray data is being analyzed, then "of" is used to indicate relation.

> To better understand the results, we must perform a principal component analysis **of** the microarray data.

If the microarray data is the *outcome* of the analysis, then "for" is used to indicate attempting to obtain, gain, or acquire.

> We suspected the flux capacitor might contain microarray data, so we decided to perform a principal component analysis (of the flux capacitor to search) **for** it.

Where "it" is the microarray data.

Another pair of simpler examples:

If we seek the maguffin, then we might

> search his luggage **for** the maguffin

If we suspect kryptonite is hidden within the maguffin, then we might

> Perform a search **of** the maguffin seeking kryptonite

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to clarify: microarray data is a special kind of data and principal component analysis is a method *of* analyzing it. I hope I used it correctly :-).

Comment: @suncoolsu - You're welcome. Then in your case, analysis **of** data is the best usage